# IE 11 and Edge: falsely claim to be in orientation: portrait

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have the following media queries:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    .cover-image {
        background-image: url("...");
    }
}


@media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .cover-image {
        background-image: url("...");
    }
}
```

The intent is to show a mobile-specific image if the screen is in portrait.

On initially loading the page in IE11 or Edge, `orientation:portrait` rule is applied and the image intended for mobile loads. On a subsequent refresh, via the button or F5, the `orientation:landscape` rule is applied instead and the proper image loads.

Attempted summary: IE/Edge thinks it's in portrait mode for the initial load, landscape mode for any reloads.

I know it's been said many times, in many ways, but what is IE doing? And why is it doing it?

Thanks.

EDIT: better explanation of CSS.